# Design-time data in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm creating an application in WPF using EntityFramework. I would like to be able to see data from my database in design time, to speed up production.
Following the MVVM pattern, I've created a ViewModel for my view which will grab the data from the database and display it in my view. I've instantiated a new ViewModel in the code behind of the View and everything works at runtime.
I understand that at design time the ctor for the ViewModel does not run, so naturally no data is shown.
I was wondering if there was a way to change this, either to show the actual data in the view at design time, or eventually mock data just to be able to see the design of my datagrid in real time.

Thanks

Comment: This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx) might help you.